# "My orders" showing everyones orders in my page

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

suppose when I logged in using google sign in my app then I order the food and if anyone orders food from other app with other account if user orders then my orders can show me his orders and his orders are getting loaded into my including my orders . so, every user can see everyones order. help me to solve this problem.

```
    package com.food.sheenishere.stark;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.Common.Common;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model.Request;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.ViewHolder.OrderViewHolder;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class OrderStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request,OrderViewHolder> adapter;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);
        //firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests=database.getReference("Requests");

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadOrders();


    }

    private void loadOrders() {


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_layout,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests.orderByChild("name")

        ) {



            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
                viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());
                viewHolder.txtOrderName.setText(model.getName());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private String convertCodeToStatus(String status) {
        if (status.equals("0"))
            return "placed  ";
        else if (status.equals("1"))
            return "On my way";
        else
            return "Shipped   ";
    }
}
```

com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model.Request

```
 package com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by WAHDAT KASHMIRI on 12-09-2017.
 */

public class Request {
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String total;
    private String status;
    private List<Order> foods; //list of food order


    public Request() {
    }


    public Request(String phone, String name, String address, String total, List<Order> foods) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.total = total;
        this.status = "0"; //default is 0, 0:placed, 1 : shipping ,2:shipped
        this.foods = foods;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<Order> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public void setFoods(List<Order> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your requests contain a way to identify who's order it is?  You would use that field to only retrieve the orders for the user you want to show.

Comment: sir give me idea how to do hat

Comment: Please post your code for com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model.Request

Comment: sie @NicholasSmith I have edited my question with com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model.Request code

Comment: Somewhere in your app do you have a unique ID of the logged in person?  You would need to add that field to your Request class, so you can identify to which user each Request belongs.  Check this document if you're using Google sign in for Android. getId()  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getId()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a userId to your Request model.

```
private String userId;
```

Populate that with the user who created the request.  Then later, when you are retrieving records to display, only retrieve records for the current logged-in user by `userId`.

If you're using Android Google Sign On, see this section of documentation for a source of unique identifier for the user:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getId()